# 403 / 500 Error after Update to Drupal 7.50

Tags: apache, .htaccess, drupal-7, http-status-code-403, http-status-code-500

I just updated one of my projects (https://www.frank-thomsen.eu/) I manage to Drupal 7.50 and after that I get all the time an 403 error like that

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server. Server unable to
>   read htaccess file, denying access to be safe
>
> Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

when I use 644 or 744 on every file and an 500 error, when I change the .htaccess to 755.

I have tryed to use a backup. Nothing!

So also the Login-Page doesn't work. And like I said I cannot find the error! 
A test-page in a subdirectory works -> https://www.frank-thomsen.eu/test/hhvm_test.php

So, what could it be?

Greetings and best wishes!

Answer (score 0):

when you updated have you done something with the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely check file ownership of all files and folders, in addition to file permissions. I had a similar problem back with 7.43 (or thereabouts), and for some reason during the update the owner and group of the files was changed. This command may help:

```
sudo chown -R YOUR-USER:YOUR-GROUP drupal-root-folder/
```

Replace YOUR-USER and YOUR-GROUP with the appropriate values for your server. This set file ownerships back to what thye should be. Hope that helps!